# Why do I get "QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal" with a custom dialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qt-signals

I am using Qt5.

I have a very simple dialog class that inherits from QDialog.

I have a class that uses this dialog, and also a QFileDialog:

```
    NameDlg       m_name_dlg;
    QFileDialog   m_file_dlg;
```

This class also has some slots to handle dialog closing:

```
private slots:
    void on_dlgName_accepted();
    void on_FileDlgClosed(int result);
```

In the constructor I do some connecting:

```
QObject::connect(&m_file_dlg, SIGNAL(finished(int)),
                 this, SLOT(on_FileDlgClosed(int)));
QObject::connect(&m_name_dlg, SIGNAL(accepted()),
                 this, SLOT(on_dlgName_accepted()));
```

The first call to connect is fine, but the second call generates the output:

```
QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName: No matching signal for on_dlgName_accepted()
```

Curiously, my slot is correctly called when the name dialog is accepted!

The documentation (and header file) for QDialog says:

```
Signals
    void accepted()
```

So it isn't a parameter mismatch.

As I said above, the signal is correctly called so my code all works fine, I just would really really like to understand why I get this warning (as an educational exercise) and also get rid of it (for peace of mind).

I cannot post full code, but I do believe there should be enough for anyone to understand the problem.

Things I have tried:

1. Using finished() instead.
2. Casting `&m_name_dialog` to a `QDialog *`.
3. Changing the signal to `QDialog::accepted()`.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some part of your code you are using the method [`connectSlotsByName`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName), if you have created a design (**.ui**) this usually calls it since compiling generates a file `ui_somefile.h`, and this file is used.

According to the [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmetaobject.html#connectSlotsByName):

> **void QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName(QObject *object)**
>
> Searches recursively for all child objects of the given object, and
>   connects matching signals from them to slots of object that follow the
>   following form:
>
> `void on_<object name>_<signal name>(<signal parameters>);`

From the above it is observed that this method will try to connect the slots that have that format, and in your case the second slot fulfills it, when trying to connect it looks for the objects and signals but in your case it does not find it since the object does not exist `dlgName` and generates the warning you see.

This method is created by the .ui file because through the design you can create slots by right clicking on the widget and selecting **go to slot**, choosing the signal and finally creating the slot.

---

**Note:**

If you are going to create your own slot, **avoid using the underscores** as this could cause you problems because Qt would try to connect it and if the objects do not exist it will send you several warnings.

Comment: Amazingly well spotted! I changed my function from on_... to when_... and the warning went. Thanks!